# " Query was empty " error on empty image upload form field

Tags: php, mysql

Hi Guys i have a mysql dbase with various fields , one of which stores the file/URL to an image location. User can update / edit  the dbase when required by pre populating an php update form with that particular records data, and re-submit the changes.

it all works well except when user leaves the " Upload Image" form field blank , they then get the error " Query Was Empty" .

The reason the upload image field is left blank is because it already has an image on the dbase for that record and would like to keep it, but still update any other required data.

Also when prepopulating the update form, it cannot prepopulate the image upload field , which i believe is for security purposes, so if user does not browse to select an image and leaves the field blank , it will wipe the existing image on dbase when the form was eventually processed.

Currently i use validation to find empty form fields and point user to go back and upload an image.

I dont know how to overcome the issue without using validation to force user to re upload an image which they may not know how to do or even want to.

Any Ideas ?

```
<?php
// get variables from form post for which record to change, and what to do with it
$action = $_GET['action'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

// THE DELETE OPTION
if($action == 'delete')
{
// set up delete query
$query = "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id ='$id' ";
// do the query
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
echo "<center><h3><font color=#000000>Deleted Successfully!</font></h3>";
}
// THE ADD OR EDIT OPTION
elseif (isset($_POST['add']) || isset($_POST['edit']))
{
//ADD
// File upload handling
if (isset($_POST['add'])&& $_FILES['field_3']['name']!='')
{
$field_3_filename = "file_3_".date("sihdmY").substr($_FILES['field_3']['name'],strlen($_FILES['field_3']['name'])-4);

if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['field_3']['tmp_name'], "./files/".$field_3_filename))
{
 die("File " .  $_FILES['field_3']['name'] . " was not uploaded.");
}

// set up insert query
$query = "INSERT into tablename(,field_1,field_2,field_3) VALUES ('" . $_POST['field_1'] . "','" . $_POST['field_2'] . "','" . "./files/".$field_3_filename . "')";
}
//EDIT
if (isset($_POST['edit'])&& $_FILES['field_3']['name']!='')
{
$field_3_filename = "file_3_".date("sihdmY").substr($_FILES['field_3']['name'],strlen($_FILES['field_3']['name'])-4);

if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['field_3']['tmp_name'], "./files/".$field_3_filename))
{
 die("File " .  $_FILES['field_3']['name'] . " was not uploaded.");
}
//Post..Variables..for..Update
$name = $_POST['field_1'];
$email = $_POST['field_2'];
$image  = $_POST['field_3'];

//UPDATE..QUERY
$query = "UPDATE tablename SET field_1 = '$name',field_2 = '$email',field_3 = '" . "./files/".$field_3_filename . "' WHERE id='$id'";
}
//DO...QUERY
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<center><h3><font color=#000000>Updated Successfully!</font></h3>
<br />";

//EDIT FORM
}
else
{
   // load stored values for editing event but not image field as will not prepopulate field due to security
   if($action == 'edit')
   {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id='$id'";
      $result = mysql_query($query);
      $name = mysql_result($result,0,"field_1");
      $email = mysql_result($result,0,"field_2");
   }
?>
```

Comment: Would you please add your `update sql` query to your question to better understand the problem?

Comment: Could you Please write your SQL here......?

Answer (score 0):

Well only upload/update the db-table-field when the user sends an image. If not, than don't touch this field:

```
<?php
// Check if form was submitted
if(count($_POST) > 0)
{
    // Check if new image was uploaded
    if(isset($_FILE) && !empty($_FILE['image']['tmp_name']))
    {
          // Here update the whole db-table, also the image/url-column...
    }
    else
    {
         // Here update the db-table, but not the image/url-column...
    }

}
```